# Why are many FHSS / DSSS transcievers limited to 63 mW?

Tags: legal, diy, digital-modes, rf-power, uhf

While researching a DIY digital video streaming solution for an outdoor quad-rotor project, I've noticed that a lot of the popular digital transceivers seem to be limited to 63mW transmit power:

- http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/zigbee-mesh-module/xbee-zb-module#specs
- http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/zigbee-mesh-module/xbee-digimesh-2-4#specs
- http://wireless.murata.com/datasheet?/RFM/data/dnt2400c.pdf
- http://wireless.murata.com/datasheet?/RFM/data/dnt900dk_manual.pdf

(sorry, newbs can't post too many links)

My original guess was that it was a legislation issue, but the last module (that operates on 900MHz unlike the other 2.4GHz ones) has the following message in the datasheet:

`Selectable 1, 10, 63, 250, 500 or 1000 mW transmit power with a firmware interlock of 63 mW maximum for 500 kb/s operation`

That would suggest that something in the underlying physics breaks down above 63 mW for high bitrates. Is that the case, or is it just a combination of coincidence and poorly written datasheets (the third module is rated for 63 mW on its datasheet, but 100 mW on its specs page)?.

About me:

I'm an established programmer with a decent understanding of physics (albeit I'll admit to skipping quite a few electrical engineering classes) so as long as you keep it below line integrals and wave functions (the quantum type), I should be able to follow.

Comment: It's extremely implausible that this is a limit of physics rather than regulation. I don't have info on where this particular limit actually comes from, though.

Comment: The devices you posted all use the ISM band. Regulations are created to protect persons against health risks and interference to other pre-existing services. The main concern about microwave frequencies, is non-ionizing radiation which can cause localized heating (http://www.arrl.org/rf-radiation-and-electromagnetic-field-safety). This is the FCC's rules explained by the ARRL: http://www.arrl.org/the-fcc-s-new-rf-exposure-regulations

Comment: So why is the 63mW limit imposed only if operating at 500kb/s? Or am I reading the specs wrong and they're supposed to read: "it can do 1000 mW transmission, but you have to change the firmware" ?

Comment: You've got to ask your technical contacts at the supplier for that information. That is probably proprietary information.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely they are complying with the ERP limits imposed by the government. The different powers could have to do with the gain of the antenna at different frequencies.